# Using XPath 1.0 with HTML to match elements that aren't in a parent

Tags: html, xpath, parent

Consider this HTML:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="cal-date">1</a>
        <div class="checkin-time">6 AM | 8h 30m</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would like to use XPath 1.0 to return `6 AM | 8h 30m` while matching the class (`cal-date`) and text contents (`1`) in `<a class="cal-date">1</a>`.  The `<a>` isn't a parent or anything, so I'm a little lost.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

XPath has the concept of [axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) (that’s plural of axis, not things for cutting down trees). The default axis is the `child::` axis, so if you don’t specify it your query will be searching the children of the previous node. You can create more complex queries by using different axes.

In this case you probably want to use the `following-sibling::` axis. First select `a` element as usual, then in the next location step of your query specify the `following-sibling::` axis to search the siblings of the `a` node rather than its children:

```
//a[@class='cal-date' and . = '1']/following-sibling::div
```

If you need to you can be more specific with the `div` query, as with “normal” XPath, and can continue the query after the change of axis. For example if your HTML was more complex and looked like this:

```html
<a class="cal-date">1</a>
<div>A decoy div</div>
<div>
  <span>Not this</span>
  <span class="checkin-time">6 AM | 8h 30m</span>
  <span> Not this either</span>
</div>
```

you could get at the `checkin-time` span with an XPath expression like this:

```
//a[@class='cal-date' and . = '1']/following-sibling::div[2]/span[@class='checkin-time']
```

Note that when selecting the `span` element, after the `following-sibling::div` part, the axis isn’t specified so it uses the default of `child::`, because we are looking for children of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `following-sibling` for this. Alternatively, search for `<div/>` elements contained by table cells which contain the link you're looking for.

```
//td[a[@class='cal-date' and . = '1']]/div
```